# Spring Boot App does not deploy on Glassfish 4.1

Tags: java, spring, glassfish, spring-boot

I have a vanilla spring boot app that consists of the following pom.xml

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>xxx.alexius</groupId>
    <artifactId>myapp</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>

    <name>my app</name>
<description>Core Application Platform</description>
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.2.2.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>
<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <java.version>1.7</java.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-mobile</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-social-facebook</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-social-twitter</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
        <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
        <version>9.4-1201-jdbc41</version>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.2</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.7</source>
                <target>1.7</target>
                <compilerArgument>-Xlint:all</compilerArgument>
                <showWarnings>true</showWarnings>
                <showDeprecation>true</showDeprecation>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

When I deploy this to a Tomcat everything works fine but when I try to deploy this on a Glassfish 4.1 server I get the following error

```
SEVERE:   Class [ liquibase/integration/spring/SpringLiquibase ] not found. Error while loading [ class org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.liquibase.LiquibaseAutoConfiguration$LiquibaseConfiguration ]
SEVERE:   Exception while deploying the app [platform]
SEVERE:   Exception during lifecycle processing
java.lang.ArrayStoreException: sun.reflect.annotation.TypeNotPresentExceptionProxy
```

Any ideas on what is going wrong? Is it a Spring or Glassfish bug?

Comment: is http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.liquibase/liquibase-core/3.2.2 in your classpath?

Comment: Well its not its my pom so probably not but the spring-boot should have all dependencies needed in its pom. The rest of the project just an empty project and has no extra code. Just need to deploy it with no functionality so I can start working on it.

Comment: execute mvn dependency:tree to see whether liquibase is in your classpath.

Comment: Spring Boot does some checking which classes are available on the class path to determine which auto configuration to apply. For this it tries to load classes and catches the `ClassNotFoundExceptions`. So I would guess that either that mechanism doesn't work in GlassFish (not sure why it should) or glass fish is broken or includes other classes which interfere with class detections or auto config.

Comment: I added the dependency 

`<groupId>org.liquibase</groupId>
            <artifactId>liquibase-core</artifactId>
            <version>3.3.2</version>`

and now I get 

`SEVERE:   Exception while deploying the app [platform]
SEVERE:   Exception during lifecycle processing
java.lang.ArrayStoreException: sun.reflect.annotation.TypeNotPresentExceptionProxy`

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It looks like this a bug in Glassfish: [GLASSFISH-21265](https://java.net/jira/browse/GLASSFISH-21265)

You can try to get around that by adding `metadata-complete="true"` in your `web.xml` like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="3.1" 
         metadata-complete="true"
         xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee" 
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd">
</web-app>
```

> The metadata-complete="true" indicates that the JAR files in
>   /WEB-INF/lib doesn't need to be scanned for Servlet 3.0 specific
>   annotations, but the webapp's own classes will still be scanned.

See also:

- [Spring Boot on Glassfish](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28737018/spring-boot-on-glassfish)
- [Spring Boot app deployed to Glassfish is giving strange results](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22864509/spring-boot-app-deployed-to-glassfish-is-giving-strange-results)
- [Cannot deploy simple project on Glassfish 3.1.2 and 4.0.0+](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/1355)
- [Spring.io Blog - Deploying Spring Boot Applications](https://spring.io/blog/2014/03/07/deploying-spring-boot-applications)

Comment: I try OK with version 1.x. But when I try with Spring Boot 2.x. It don't work. Is Glassfish Server good for Spring Boot?

Comment: at the moment I have issues deploying Spring Boot 2 application to Glassfish 4.1.2 - probably they boil down to the fact that Glassfish uses older Jackson libraries that interfere with those that Maven/Spring Boot pack into the WAR. probably should switch to Glassfish 5, which is not an option for me