# spring boot 2 with payara server 5 - multiple class error

Tags: java, spring-boot, payara

I want to deploy a spring boot 2 application on payara server and I get the following errors

```
  Class [ com/samskivert/mustache/Mustache$Collector ] not found. Error while loading [ class org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.mustache.MustacheAutoConfiguration ]]]

[2020-06-04T14:33:58.760+0200] [Payara 5.201] [SEVERE] [] [Annotation-Framework] [tid: _ThreadID=313 _ThreadName=admin-thread-pool::admin-listener(2)] [timeMillis: 1591274038760] [levelValue: 1000] [[
  Class [ groovy/text/markup/TemplateConfiguration ] not found. Error while loading [ class org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.groovy.template.GroovyTemplateAutoConfiguration$GroovyMarkupConfiguration ]]]

[2020-06-04T14:33:58.776+0200] [Payara 5.201] [SEVERE] [] [Annotation-Framework] [tid: _ThreadID=313 _ThreadName=admin-thread-pool::admin-listener(2)] [timeMillis: 1591274038776] [levelValue: 1000] [[
  Class [ org/springframework/mail/javamail/JavaMailSenderImpl ] not found. Error while loading [ class org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.mail.MailSenderValidatorAutoConfiguration ]]]

[2020-06-04T14:33:58.791+0200] [Payara 5.201] [SEVERE] [] [Annotation-Framework] [tid: _ThreadID=313 _ThreadName=admin-thread-pool::admin-listener(2)] [timeMillis: 1591274038791] [levelValue: 1000] [[
  Class [ Lcom/unboundid/ldap/listener/InMemoryDirectoryServer; ] not found. Error while loading [ class org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.ldap.embedded.EmbeddedLdapAutoConfiguration ]]]

[2020-06-04T14:33:58.796+0200] [Payara 5.201] [SEVERE] [] [Annotation-Framework] [tid: _ThreadID=313 _ThreadName=admin-thread-pool::admin-listener(2)] [timeMillis: 1591274038796] [levelValue: 1000] [[
  Class [ org/thymeleaf/spring5/templateresolver/SpringResourceTemplateResolver ] not found. Error while loading [ class org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.thymeleaf.ThymeleafAutoConfiguration$DefaultTemplateResolverConfiguration ]]]
```

the application works correctly despite this but I would like to solve the problems for the production

here is my pom file

i used spring initializr with intelij

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.0.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>x.x</groupId>
    <artifactId>demo-spring-tomcat</artifactId>
    <version>0.1</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <name>demo-spring-tomcat</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

    <properties>
        <java.version>11</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
                    <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <!-- added to avoid an error -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-batch</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

and my two class

```java
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.SpringBootServletInitializer;

@SpringBootApplication
public class DemoSpringTomcatApplication extends SpringBootServletInitializer {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(DemoSpringTomcatApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

```java
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ResponseBody;

@Controller
@RequestMapping("/messages")
@ResponseBody
public class RestController {
    @GetMapping("/welcome")
    public String welcome() {
        return "<strong>Hello, Welcome to Spring Boot!</strong>";
    }
}
```

Can someone help me understand the errors, thanks

Comment: Similar question already asked https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33083368/how-to-deploy-spring-boot-application-on-glassfish-4-1-1

Comment: I tried the solutions shown, but none worked for me

Answer (score 0):

I made some modiciation and I no longer have the same error ... I understand even less those

pom.xml

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.0.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>x.x</groupId>
    <artifactId>demo-spring-tomcat</artifactId>
    <version>0.1</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <name>demo-spring-tomcat</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

    <properties>
        <java.version>11</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
                    <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

```java
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.builder.SpringApplicationBuilder;
import org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.SpringBootServletInitializer;

@SpringBootApplication
public class Application extends SpringBootServletInitializer {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }

    @Override
    protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder application) {
        return application.sources(Application.class);
    }
}
```

```java
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ResponseBody;

@Controller
@RequestMapping("/messages")
@ResponseBody
public class RestController {
    @GetMapping("/welcome")
    public String welcome() {
        return "<strong>Hello, Welcome to Spring Boot!</strong>";
    }
}
```

```java
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.ViewControllerRegistry;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurer;

@Configuration
public class WebMvcConfig {
    @Bean
    public WebMvcConfigurer forwardToIndex() {
        return new WebMvcConfigurer() {
            @Override
            public void addViewControllers(ViewControllerRegistry registry) {
                registry.addViewController("/admin").setViewName(
                        "forward:/admin/index.html");
                registry.addViewController("/").setViewName(
                        "forward:/public/index.html");
            }
        };
    }
}
```

I created two index.html files... + added beans.xml file...

```
[2020-06-05T09:06:16.683+0200] [Payara 5.201] [WARNING] [] [javax.enterprise.system.core] [tid: _ThreadID=176 _ThreadName=background-preinit] [timeMillis: 1591340776683] [levelValue: 900] [[
  APIClassLoader.loadClass() caused exception
org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Unable to resolve com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat.jackson-dataformat-xml [212](R 212.0): missing requirement [com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat.jackson-dataformat-xml [212](R 212.0)] osgi.wiring.package; (&(osgi.wiring.package=org.codehaus.stax2)(version>=4.2.0)(!(version>=5.0.0))) Unresolved requirements: [[com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat.jackson-dataformat-xml [212](R 212.0)] osgi.wiring.package; (&(osgi.wiring.package=org.codehaus.stax2)(version>=4.2.0)(!(version>=5.0.0)))]
    at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.resolveBundleRevision(Felix.java:4368)
    at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.loadBundleClass(Felix.java:2068)
    at org.apache.felix.framework.BundleImpl.loadClass(BundleImpl.java:978)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.osgiadapter.OSGiModuleImpl$4$1.run(OSGiModuleImpl.java:441)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.osgiadapter.OSGiModuleImpl$4$1.run(OSGiModuleImpl.java:438)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.osgiadapter.OSGiModuleImpl$4.loadClass(OSGiModuleImpl.java:438)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:521)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.APIClassLoaderServiceImpl$APIClassLoader.loadClass(APIClassLoaderServiceImpl.java:260)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:575)
    at com.sun.enterprise.loader.CurrentBeforeParentClassLoader.loadClass(CurrentBeforeParentClassLoader.java:83)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:575)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:521)
    at org.glassfish.web.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1684)
    at org.glassfish.web.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1583)
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:398)
    at org.springframework.util.ClassUtils.forName(ClassUtils.java:285)
    at org.springframework.util.ClassUtils.isPresent(ClassUtils.java:355)
    at org.springframework.http.converter.support.AllEncompassingFormHttpMessageConverter.<clinit>(AllEncompassingFormHttpMessageConverter.java:56)
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.BackgroundPreinitializer$MessageConverterInitializer.run(BackgroundPreinitializer.java:129)
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.BackgroundPreinitializer$1.runSafely(BackgroundPreinitializer.java:104)
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.BackgroundPreinitializer$1.run(BackgroundPreinitializer.java:96)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
]]

[2020-06-05T09:06:18.396+0200] [Payara 5.201] [WARNING] [] [javax.enterprise.system.core] [tid: _ThreadID=116 _ThreadName=admin-thread-pool::admin-listener(1)] [timeMillis: 1591340778396] [levelValue: 900] [[
  APIClassLoader.loadClass() caused exception
org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Unable to resolve com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat.jackson-dataformat-xml [212](R 212.0): missing requirement [com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat.jackson-dataformat-xml [212](R 212.0)] osgi.wiring.package; (&(osgi.wiring.package=org.codehaus.stax2)(version>=4.2.0)(!(version>=5.0.0))) Unresolved requirements: [[com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat.jackson-dataformat-xml [212](R 212.0)] osgi.wiring.package; (&(osgi.wiring.package=org.codehaus.stax2)(version>=4.2.0)(!(version>=5.0.0)))]
    at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.resolveBundleRevision(Felix.java:4368)
    at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.loadBundleClass(Felix.java:2068)
    at org.apache.felix.framework.BundleImpl.loadClass(BundleImpl.java:978)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.osgiadapter.OSGiModuleImpl$4$1.run(OSGiModuleImpl.java:441)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.osgiadapter.OSGiModuleImpl$4$1.run(OSGiModuleImpl.java:438)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.osgiadapter.OSGiModuleImpl$4.loadClass(OSGiModuleImpl.java:438)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:521)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.APIClassLoaderServiceImpl$APIClassLoader.loadClass(APIClassLoaderServiceImpl.java:260)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:575)
    at com.sun.enterprise.loader.CurrentBeforeParentClassLoader.loadClass(CurrentBeforeParentClassLoader.java:83)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:575)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:521)
    at org.glassfish.web.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1684)
    at org.glassfish.web.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1583)
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:398)
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.FilteringSpringBootCondition.resolve(FilteringSpringBootCondition.java:108)
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.FilteringSpringBootCondition$ClassNameFilter.isPresent(FilteringSpringBootCondition.java:140)
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.FilteringSpringBootCondition$ClassNameFilter$2.matches(FilteringSpringBootCondition.java:128)
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.FilteringSpringBootCondition.filter(FilteringSpringBootCondition.java:91)
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.OnClassCondition.getMatchOutcome(OnClassCondition.java:95)
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.SpringBootCondition.matches(SpringBootCondition.java:47)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConditionEvaluator.shouldSkip(ConditionEvaluator.java:108)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.processConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassParser.java:225)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.processMemberClasses(ConfigurationClassParser.java:371)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.doProcessConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassParser.java:271)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.processConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassParser.java:249)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.processImports(ConfigurationClassParser.java:599)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.doProcessConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassParser.java:310)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.processConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassParser.java:249)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.processImports(ConfigurationClassParser.java:599)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.access$800(ConfigurationClassParser.java:110)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser$DeferredImportSelectorGroupingHandler.lambda$processGroupImports$1(ConfigurationClassParser.java:811)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1540)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser$DeferredImportSelectorGroupingHandler.processGroupImports(ConfigurationClassParser.java:808)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser$DeferredImportSelectorHandler.process(ConfigurationClassParser.java:779)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.parse(ConfigurationClassParser.java:192)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.processConfigBeanDefinitions(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:319)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.postProcessBeanDefinitionRegistry(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:236)
    at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanDefinitionRegistryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:280)
    at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:96)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:706)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:532)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:143)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:758)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:750)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:397)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:315)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.SpringBootServletInitializer.run(SpringBootServletInitializer.java:191)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.SpringBootServletInitializer.createRootApplicationContext(SpringBootServletInitializer.java:171)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.SpringBootServletInitializer.onStartup(SpringBootServletInitializer.java:95)
    at org.springframework.web.SpringServletContainerInitializer.onStartup(SpringServletContainerInitializer.java:172)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.callServletContainerInitializers(StandardContext.java:5835)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebModule.callServletContainerInitializers(WebModule.java:738)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:5733)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebModule.start(WebModule.java:619)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:958)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:941)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:694)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebContainer.loadWebModule(WebContainer.java:1877)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebContainer.loadWebModule(WebContainer.java:1608)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebApplication.start(WebApplication.java:108)
    at org.glassfish.internal.data.EngineRef.start(EngineRef.java:123)
[2020-06-05T09:06:19.535+0200] [Payara 5.201] [WARNING] [] [javax.enterprise.system.core] [tid: _ThreadID=116 _ThreadName=admin-thread-pool::admin-listener(1)] [timeMillis: 1591340779535] [levelValue: 900] [[
  APIClassLoader.loadClass() caused exception
org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Unable to resolve com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat.jackson-dataformat-xml [212](R 212.0): missing requirement [com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat.jackson-dataformat-xml [212](R 212.0)] osgi.wiring.package; (&(osgi.wiring.package=org.codehaus.stax2)(version>=4.2.0)(!(version>=5.0.0))) Unresolved requirements: [[com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat.jackson-dataformat-xml [212](R 212.0)] osgi.wiring.package; (&(osgi.wiring.package=org.codehaus.stax2)(version>=4.2.0)(!(version>=5.0.0)))]
    at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.resolveBundleRevision(Felix.java:4368)
    at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.loadBundleClass(Felix.java:2068)
    at org.apache.felix.framework.BundleImpl.loadClass(BundleImpl.java:978)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.osgiadapter.OSGiModuleImpl$4$1.run(OSGiModuleImpl.java:441)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.osgiadapter.OSGiModuleImpl$4$1.run(OSGiModuleImpl.java:438)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.osgiadapter.OSGiModuleImpl$4.loadClass(OSGiModuleImpl.java:438)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:521)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.APIClassLoaderServiceImpl$APIClassLoader.loadClass(APIClassLoaderServiceImpl.java:260)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:575)
    at com.sun.enterprise.loader.CurrentBeforeParentClassLoader.loadClass(CurrentBeforeParentClassLoader.java:83)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:575)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:521)
    at org.glassfish.web.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1684)
    at org.glassfish.web.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1583)
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:398)
    at org.springframework.util.ClassUtils.forName(ClassUtils.java:285)
    at org.springframework.util.ClassUtils.isPresent(ClassUtils.java:355)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurationSupport.<clinit>(WebMvcConfigurationSupport.java:201)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:490)
    at org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.instantiateClass(BeanUtils.java:204)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:117)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:310)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:295)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireConstructor(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1358)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1204)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:557)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:517)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:323)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:226)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:321)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:895)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:878)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:550)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:143)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:758)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:750)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:397)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:315)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.SpringBootServletInitializer.run(SpringBootServletInitializer.java:191)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.SpringBootServletInitializer.createRootApplicationContext(SpringBootServletInitializer.java:171)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.SpringBootServletInitializer.onStartup(SpringBootServletInitializer.java:95)
    at org.springframework.web.SpringServletContainerInitializer.onStartup(SpringServletContainerInitializer.java:172)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.callServletContainerInitializers(StandardContext.java:5835)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebModule.callServletContainerInitializers(WebModule.java:738)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:5733)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebModule.start(WebModule.java:619)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:958)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:941)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:694)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebContainer.loadWebModule(WebContainer.java:1877)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebContainer.loadWebModule(WebContainer.java:1608)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebApplication.start(WebApplication.java:108)
    at org.glassfish.internal.data.EngineRef.start(EngineRef.java:123)
```

Note one of the errors can be resolved by adding the following dependency

```xml
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-dataformat-xml</artifactId>
            <version>2.10.2</version>
        </dependency>
```

```
[2020-06-05T09:16:18.799+0200] [Payara 5.201] [WARNING] [] [javax.enterprise.system.core] [tid: _ThreadID=193 _ThreadName=background-preinit] [timeMillis: 1591341378799] [levelValue: 900] [[
  APIClassLoader.loadClass() caused exception
org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Unable to resolve com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat.jackson-dataformat-xml [212](R 212.0): missing requirement [com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat.jackson-dataformat-xml [212](R 212.0)] osgi.wiring.package; (&(osgi.wiring.package=org.codehaus.stax2)(version>=4.2.0)(!(version>=5.0.0))) Unresolved requirements: [[com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat.jackson-dataformat-xml [212](R 212.0)] osgi.wiring.package; (&(osgi.wiring.package=org.codehaus.stax2)(version>=4.2.0)(!(version>=5.0.0)))]
    at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.resolveBundleRevision(Felix.java:4368)
    at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.loadBundleClass(Felix.java:2068)
    at org.apache.felix.framework.BundleImpl.loadClass(BundleImpl.java:978)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.osgiadapter.OSGiModuleImpl$4$1.run(OSGiModuleImpl.java:441)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.osgiadapter.OSGiModuleImpl$4$1.run(OSGiModuleImpl.java:438)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.osgiadapter.OSGiModuleImpl$4.loadClass(OSGiModuleImpl.java:438)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:521)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.APIClassLoaderServiceImpl$APIClassLoader.loadClass(APIClassLoaderServiceImpl.java:260)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:575)
    at com.sun.enterprise.loader.CurrentBeforeParentClassLoader.loadClass(CurrentBeforeParentClassLoader.java:83)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:575)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:521)
    at org.glassfish.web.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1684)
    at org.glassfish.web.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1583)
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:398)
    at org.springframework.util.ClassUtils.forName(ClassUtils.java:285)
    at org.springframework.util.ClassUtils.isPresent(ClassUtils.java:355)
    at org.springframework.http.converter.support.AllEncompassingFormHttpMessageConverter.<clinit>(AllEncompassingFormHttpMessageConverter.java:56)
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.BackgroundPreinitializer$MessageConverterInitializer.run(BackgroundPreinitializer.java:129)
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.BackgroundPreinitializer$1.runSafely(BackgroundPreinitializer.java:104)
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.BackgroundPreinitializer$1.run(BackgroundPreinitializer.java:96)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
]]

[2020-06-05T09:16:19.370+0200] [Payara 5.201] [WARNING] [] [javax.enterprise.system.core] [tid: _ThreadID=193 _ThreadName=background-preinit] [timeMillis: 1591341379370] [levelValue: 900] [[
  APIClassLoader.loadClass() caused exception
org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Unable to resolve com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat.jackson-dataformat-xml [212](R 212.0): missing requirement [com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat.jackson-dataformat-xml [212](R 212.0)] osgi.wiring.package; (&(osgi.wiring.package=org.codehaus.stax2)(version>=4.2.0)(!(version>=5.0.0))) Unresolved requirements: [[com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat.jackson-dataformat-xml [212](R 212.0)] osgi.wiring.package; (&(osgi.wiring.package=org.codehaus.stax2)(version>=4.2.0)(!(version>=5.0.0)))]
    at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.resolveBundleRevision(Felix.java:4368)
    at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.loadBundleClass(Felix.java:2068)
    at org.apache.felix.framework.BundleImpl.loadClass(BundleImpl.java:978)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.osgiadapter.OSGiModuleImpl$4$1.run(OSGiModuleImpl.java:441)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.osgiadapter.OSGiModuleImpl$4$1.run(OSGiModuleImpl.java:438)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.osgiadapter.OSGiModuleImpl$4.loadClass(OSGiModuleImpl.java:438)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:521)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.APIClassLoaderServiceImpl$APIClassLoader.loadClass(APIClassLoaderServiceImpl.java:260)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:575)
    at com.sun.enterprise.loader.CurrentBeforeParentClassLoader.loadClass(CurrentBeforeParentClassLoader.java:83)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:575)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:521)
    at org.glassfish.web.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1684)
    at org.glassfish.web.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1583)
    at org.springframework.http.converter.json.Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder$XmlObjectMapperInitializer.create(Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder.java:888)
    at org.springframework.http.converter.json.Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder.build(Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder.java:647)
    at org.springframework.http.converter.xml.MappingJackson2XmlHttpMessageConverter.<init>(MappingJackson2XmlHttpMessageConverter.java:52)
    at org.springframework.http.converter.support.AllEncompassingFormHttpMessageConverter.<init>(AllEncompassingFormHttpMessageConverter.java:86)
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.BackgroundPreinitializer$MessageConverterInitializer.run(BackgroundPreinitializer.java:129)
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.BackgroundPreinitializer$1.runSafely(BackgroundPreinitializer.java:104)
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.BackgroundPreinitializer$1.run(BackgroundPreinitializer.java:96)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
]]
```

someone know what the mistakes are about if above, i didn't find much information ?

with code if I launch with payara micro 5.201 I don't get an error.

Note thanks to this configuration, Spring Boot tomcat Embedded still works, which was not the case before ...

Comment: I solved this by adding 

    <payara-web-app>
         <class-loader delegate="false" />
    </payara-web-app>

to the payara-web.xml 
and explicitly adding the jackson deps

     <dependency>
   <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat</groupId>
   <artifactId>jackson-dataformat-xml</artifactId>
  </dependency>

hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

For your jackson XML problem...I solved this by adding

```
<payara-web-app>
     <class-loader delegate="false" />
</payara-web-app>
```

to the payara-web.xml 
and explicitly adding the jackson deps

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-dataformat-xml</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```

hope this helps.

However I have still the Annotation-Framework errors. How did you solve it?

Comment: I did not solve it, it was finally an idea bug ...

Note some starter spring helps to solve the problem ... like starter spring batch

but I never arrive corrected all the errors ...

Comment: I added a ticket at payara, because it should be directly taken care of ... https://github.com/payara/Payara/issues/4715